# Undefined function rebar3 using elxir 1.13.4 and otp 25

Tags: compilation, rebar3

```
mix do deps.get, compile
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  castore 0.1.17
  connection 1.1.0
  cowboy 2.9.0
  cowboy_telemetry 0.4.0
  cowlib 2.11.0
  db_connection 2.4.2
  decimal 2.0.0
  ecto 3.8.4
  ecto_sql 3.8.3
  esbuild 0.5.0
  gettext 0.20.0
  jason 1.3.0
  mime 2.0.2
  phoenix 1.6.11
  phoenix_ecto 4.4.0
  phoenix_html 3.2.0
  phoenix_live_dashboard 0.6.5
  phoenix_live_view 0.17.11
  phoenix_pubsub 2.1.1
  phoenix_view 1.1.2
  plug 1.13.6
  plug_cowboy 2.5.2
  plug_crypto 1.2.2
  postgrex 0.16.4
  ranch 1.8.0
  swoosh 1.7.3
  telemetry 1.1.0
  telemetry_metrics 0.6.1
  telemetry_poller 1.0.0
All dependencies are up to date
==> connection
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated connection app
==> decimal
Compiling 4 files (.ex)
Generated decimal app
==> mime
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated mime app
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Aug-2022::02:32:45.712859 ===
beam/beam_load.c(148): Error loading module rebar3:
  please re-compile this module with an Erlang/OTP 25 compiler


escript: exception error: undefined function rebar3:main/1
  in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 750)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
  in call from init:start_em/1 
  in call from init:do_boot/3 
==> conduit
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :telemetry, "/home/tjay/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths /home/tjay/elixirproj/conduit/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin" command failed. Errors may have been logged above. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile telemetry", update it with "mix deps.update telemetry" or clean it with "mix deps.clean telemetry"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i cant compile or run mix phx.server without that error pumping out. i previously had rebar-2.6 but despite doing a local install of rebar3, i kept getting that error

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this and fixed it by running "mix local.rebar".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your elixir is compiled with otp/24 (refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72882383/how-do-i-recompile-rebar3-with-an-erlang-otp-25-compiler-running-elixir-1-13-4?rq=1)). You have to remove it and install the precompile version or install using the following source.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git
$ cd elixir
$ make clean test
$ export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/elixir/bin"
```